# Can't open files after changing username

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem, user-account

I use OS X Mavericks 10.9.4.

I changed my username and this may have caused that I am not able to open any files. I still can see my PDFs and photos in Preview! I get this:

> File XYZ couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

I have tried to run Repair Permissions in Disk Utility but that didn't help. I tried manually `chmod` files but didn't have a permission to do that.

The strangest thing is that I can see my photos in Preview but when I open them I get the error.

The files are not locked. The folder is not locked too and in permissions tab I can see my username "Lukas (Me)" as "Read Write" access.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all the permissions are correct on your home folder.
You can use the ACL tool on the Recovery HD to do this:

1. Boot into the Recovery HD using ⌘R.
2. Run `resetpassword` in Terminal (available from Utilities → Terminal).
3. Select your account from the drop-down list.
4. Click the Reset button for **Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs**.

Answer (score 1):

I have launched Disk Utility once restarted my computer and then did `Repair permissions` and it worked.